# Edge IE Mode and Enterprise Site List updates

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I've been testing IE mode by setting local group policy (via Edge
policy template download) and set up the site list on a network drive
(Enterprise Site Manager v2). Now I can't make any rhyme or reason on how any
updates to the Site List are propagated to the Edge clients. I can force the
update with an edge command locally but I'm testing this for enterprise
level. I read stuff about a 65 second latency time and I think it all
revolves around the version_number in the Site List XML. I've looked in the
registry but there is no site list version number key. here is a synopisis of

my testing...

1. Add [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) via Enterprise Site Mgr v2.. That +1 on the version
   number in the Site List XML and appears to do the 65 second update thing.
   [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) eventually loads in IE mode. (version number=4)
2. Manually add [www.msn.com](http://www.msn.com) to the Site List XML in notepad, not changing
   version number and nothing ever happens. The new site, [www.msn.com](http://www.msn.com), is never
   loaded in IE mode. I let that sit overnight, same thing in the morning, no
   joy for [www.msn.com](http://www.msn.com) in IE mode. (version number=4)
3. I decremented (-1) on the version number in Site List xml, [www.msn.com](http://www.msn.com)
   seems to load in IE mode after the 65 seconds thing. Still not sure about
   that 65 second thing. (version number=3)
4. I put version number back +1 in notepad, added [www.yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com) to the Site
   List, and [www.yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com) never loads in IE mode. (version number=4)
5. I decrimented (-1) version number with yahoo.com and it eventually loads yahoo.com in IE mode...but after minutes. (version number=3)

So it appears version number is the key to all of this. It appeared after 3.
above that simply changing it might cause a reload or clear some cache but
that doesn't appear to be the case. There appears to be a "lock" on version 4, which is where the Enterprise Site List Mgr v2 sits. But that should be totally independent. Seeking some insight into this and some
consistency. I'm worried about different version numbers floating around in
registries throughout the enterprise and I'm not sure what is the true
trigger for updates on the clients. And this whole cache thing. Thank you very much.

Comment: In edge://compat/enterprise....hitting the Force update button does not care about version number and everything works automatically.

So I'm just trying to get a feel for how the update and synchronizing is supposed to happen in the background. It just seems so inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I think I see how the updates propagate "consistently". I closed edge, reopened to edge://compat/enterprise, kept it open and after approximately 65 seconds, the site list and version number updated. It apparently doesn't matter the version number. So...

1. update Site List XML
2. close Edge
3. open Edge and after 65 seconds, the Site List updates automatically.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

When Edge is launched, Enterprise Site List is updated after 65 seconds, but if Edge is used within 65 seconds, users may have problems accessing the site because the previous site list is used.

If you run Edge without the site list information set in the Edge's preferences file, the site list is updated to the latest state.

However,
Preferences file without site list information should be applied to
"C:\Users(accounts)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Preferences"
file every boot.

Open the Preferences file with Notepad.
Clear and save the enterprise site list information.

As-is
"sitelist_location":"***[http://example.com/files/list.xml***","sitelist_source":1,"sitelist_version":"***25***"](http://example.com/files/list.xml***%22,%22sitelist_source%22:1,%22sitelist_version%22:%22***25***%22)

To-be
"sitelist_location":"","sitelist_source":1,"sitelist_version":""